# Reputation recalculation?

Tags: discussion, reputation-recalc

The story begins. I went to https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

My reputation was previously `966`. Really. It was. I swear.

I scanned the page and clicked <kbd>Trigger Reputation Recalc</kbd>

My reputation became `965`

Curious, I visited my reputation tab: `https://stackoverflow.com/users/<my_user_id>/<my_username>?tab=reputation`

No negative numbers today.

*Like a good little curious hairy primate ought to*, I attempted to reproduce the interaction. I went back to the [reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) and clicked <kbd>Trigger Reputation Recalc</kbd>

> Reputation cannot be recalculated more than once per day.

This is obviously by design.

How may I now convince myself that the change in reputation was a [random coincidence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation) and not a [proof of causality and by extension proof of the existence of God](http://carm.org/entropy-and-causality-used-proof-gods-existence)?

[man with the yellow hat http://www.pbs.org/parents/curiousgeorge/program/img/char_myh.gif](http://www.pbs.org/parents/curiousgeorge/program/img/char_myh.gif) Enter the Man with the Yellow Hat.

Comment: @LanceRoberts My poor [unicode monkeys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_wise_monkeys).

Comment: wasn't sure if the three little boxes were intentional or some artifact.  Probably best to put them in the body and not the title.

Comment: This is a true story, but the intent here is to make someone smile. I've done my best to adhere to question format and to keep it on topic for meta. Feel free to improve or remove if it offends.

Comment: Probably best to let them go. I figured 三猿 was a little esoteric (私は日本語を話さない), but there's not likely significant browser support for . As such they definitely don't belong in the title.

Comment: I don't have any problems with the format, though I do think your man actually needs a hat.

Comment: I agree, but this was the best one I could find in under a minute. If you or anyone else find a better one, please do switch it out `:D`

Comment: I cant find the guy with the yellow hat, he seems to have a yellow background to him ;)

Comment: @AlexanderWenzowski, I see no "Trigger" button on that page.

Comment: I don't see a Trigger Reputation Recalc button on that page

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The way the reputation recalc works, is that it computes your rep from the beginning of time, without counting Q&A that are now deleted.  I don't know how that combination removed one rep, but there are an infinite amount of ways it could have happened.

The preconditions of intelligibility already prove the existence of God, you only get to verify it.

Comment: Techically the combinations are finite, since he can't have voted on or asked/answered infinite posts. :P

Comment: Valid Point, I was waxing exuberant.