# Why is Stack Overflow showing 1207 and 1101 reputation for the same account?

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)
>   [Reputation discrepancy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113060/reputation-discrepancy)
>   [Bug with reputation display](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113666/bug-with-reputation-display)

Yesterday, my reputation was 1207 and Stack Overflow is showing 1101. Why?

[image]

Comment: Because of a reputation recalc or 53 downvotes.

Comment: you can see on left bottom corner my reputation is 1207 and on right top corner its 1101. why?

Comment: why i got downvote? you can see in picture left bottom corner my reputation is 1207 and on right top corner its 1101.

Comment: I don't know why you got 53 downvotes, but you must have done something *really, really bad*. (Such as insulting Jon Skeet or unicorns.)

Comment: but my profile is not showing any downvotes.

Comment: Well, either *you* downvoted 106 times, or there was a rep recalc.

Comment: You earned Mortarboard yesterday and yet your reputation graph shows only 135.  Since you had to exceed 200 to get the badge, it looks like ten votes or so were rescinded.  It could be due either to a deleted post or voting irregularities.

Comment: I do wonder if some algorithm is removing votes it finds questionable, without any oversight.  That doesn't seem like a good design to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most logical reason I can think of, is that the reputation in the Account section is cached (probably updated each day). The account section show the rep of each site. Recalculating this each moment could be performance madness.

As some have already said in comments, the sudden "loss" of reputation is almost always from deleted questions or fraud detection.

Answer (score 3):

See [Reputation recalculation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109451/reputation-recalculation) and a bunch of other results if you search for *reputation recalculation*.