# Bug with reputation display

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-display

I don't know if it is related to the new design, and I looked up a bit to find a similar bug report but couldn't find any.

Is there an explanation for this:

**EDIT**

So it's been more than 24 hours since I've posted it, and nothing has changed. 
Shouldn't have it been updated by now? (I mean if it's just a caching problem...).

[image]

Comment: Caching (most likely)

Comment: Same issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113453/why-is-stack-overflow-showing-1207-and-1101-reputation-for-the-same-account

Comment: Did you run a reputation recalculation that caused you to lose 10 reputation? I think the ones listed at the bottom are cached, but the main one at the top is live.

Comment: @animuson no I only got a -2 yesterday, nothing else in the last few days.

Comment: @ChrisF I never made it to 1139 points.

Comment: Even though unlikely, it could have been possible that someone upvoted an answer of yours just before it recached and then removed the upvote after. Has it updated to the correct amount yet?

Comment: @animuson possibly... not yet updated no.

Comment: Just so it's said, we all now know your email address and real name...

Comment: @cHao Can't you see it when you go on my page?

Comment: @talnicholas: Nope.  That info is hidden normally.  Only the site owners (and maybe mods, i forget) can see it.

Comment: @talnicolas - it could be that you got an up-vote, the value displayed in Accounts was updated then the up-vote was removed but the Accounts value still showed the higher value. Your headline figure will show the lower value.

Comment: Looks OK now.. so cache issue after all. Keep in mind that all the accounts data is very "expansive" so it's highly cached.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes as soon as I got new reputation points everything got back to normal. I just thought that if it was cached something like a daily check would have updated it.

Comment: __Don't close this question as a duplicate of the one listed; it's already closed as a duplicate of this one.__

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a caching issue in a few ways:

- The aggregator getting the latest reputation and badges up to the network level may be delayed up to a few minutes depending on traffic
- The account list itself is cached for **10 minutes** (panel/summary is cached separately, though the summary panel will use the tab's more detailed cache, if present)

However, we can wave our hands and make this discrepancy disappear, so why not?

In the next build, given we're already loading the user *anyway*, we'll fudge the numbers here and yank numbers off the site's current user...so though the accounts list is still cached, we'll pump in the current numbers just before display so they match the summary up top.